# Django Multiple Form Processing in same View

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am looking for some assistance in two areas for django forms processing.

1. I have a class view that overrides `post` and checks the name of the form in `request.POST` to determine which form has been submitted. based on the form submitted, I perform the appropriate actions for that form and save to the model.  That part works correctly.  I am not using a model form, just a custom html form created in the template with input fields.  See the below view and html for reference.  Is this the correct way to handle this or is there a best practice I should be following that makes use of model forms?  Code seems a bit heavy to me and non-standardized, like there should be a better way...
2. Being that I am not using model forms, the error processing has me a little confused.  How do you handle error processing on a normal html form that does not make use of django model forms?  See below in the view where notated `# ERROR HANDLING FOR FORM NEEDED` in code, specifically on the username field which is unique and validated on the model level.

views.py

```
 class ProfileView(View):

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "GET":
            # load profile data...
    
   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        if request.method == "POST":

            # check if profile_form submitted
            if 'profile_form' in request.POST:
                # get user form data
                profile_data = request.POST.dict()
                # get current user profile
                user_profile = Profile.objects.get(my_user=request.user)
                # check username entry against current
                if user_profile.username == profile_data['username']:
                    user_profile.country = profile_data['country']
                    user_profile.display_location = profile_data['display_location']
                    user_profile.organization_name = profile_data['organization']
                    user_profile.save(update_fields=['country', 'display_location','organization_name'])
                    #send success message to page
                    messages.success(request, "Success: Profile was updated.")
                else:
                    try:
                        user_profile.username = profile_data['username']
                        user_profile.country = profile_data['country']
                        user_profile.display_location = profile_data['display_location']
                        user_profile.organization_name = profile_data['organization']
                        user_profile.save(update_fields=['username', 'country', 'display_location','organization_name'])
                        #send success message to page
                        messages.success(request, "Success: Profile was updated.")
                    except:
                        # unique constraint error on username
                        # ERROR HANDLING FOR FORM NEEDED


            # check if user_name_form submitted
            if 'user_name_form' in request.POST:
                # get user form data
                user_data = request.POST.dict()
                # get current user
                user = MyUser.objects.get(email=request.user)
                user.first_name = user_data['first_name']
                user.last_name = user_data['last_name']
                user.save(update_fields=['first_name', 'last_name'])
                # send success message to page
                messages.success(request, "Success: Name was updated.")
            
        # Return Profile page view with updated data
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
```

html

```
<!--form-->
                <form id="profile" class="small" method="POST" action="{% url 'profile' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <!--Username-->
                    <label for="username">Username <span style="font-style: italic;">(create a unique display name that will appear to other users on the site)</span></label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text" id="username">@</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="username" name="username" value="{% if profile and profile.username is not None %}{{ profile.username }}{% endif %}">
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Tell us where you are from!</p>
                    <!--Country State/Province City Select-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="country" class="form-control mb-3" id="country">
                            <option value="">Select Country...</option>
                            {% for country in countries %}
                                {% if profile.country == country.name %}
                                    <option value="{{ country.name }}" id="{{ country.code }}" selected>{{ country.name }}</option>
                                {% else %}
                                    <option value="{{ country.name }}" id="{{ country.code }}">{{ country.name }}</option>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Enter your profile display location <i>(ie. City, State, Province, Region...)</i></p>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="display_location" name="display_location" placeholder="Based in..." value="{% if profile and profile.display_location is not None %}{{ profile.display_location }}{% endif %}">
                    <hr>
                    <p>Do you belong to an organization?</p>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="organization" name="organization" placeholder="Organization Name" value="{% if profile and profile.organization_name is not None %}{{ profile.organization_name }}{% endif %}">
                    <hr>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="profile_form" value="profile_form">Save</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to this problem I was able to get to, see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65675829/13795545) for a way to do this without a 3rd party app.

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky to do, so at DjangoCon a few years ago, we built a Django app to help. Have a look:

https://github.com/kennethlove/django-shapeshifter

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  In reading the docs on the project, it appears that this app produces multiple forms that must be submitted together inside of one single form tag.  That does not help me with my question above, which involves separate form validation and submission of each, within the same view.