# Django Add Field Error to Non-Model Form Field

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Can anyone help me understand how to properly send a field error back to a non-model form field in django that is not using the standard django form validation process?  Rendering the form again with error and user data still entered for correction and resubmission?

Example html for a simple username field that is validated on the model level:

```
<!--form-->
                <form id="profile" class="small" method="POST" action="{% url 'profile' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <!--Username-->
                    <label for="username">Username <span style="font-style: italic;">(create a unique display name that will appear to other users on the site)</span></label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text" id="username">@</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="username" name="username" value="{% if profile and profile.username is not None %}{{ profile.username }}{% endif %}">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="profile_form" value="profile_form">Save</button>
                </form>
```

View

```
class ProfileView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # get request...


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "POST":
            # check if profile_form submitted
            if 'profile_form' in request.POST:
                # get user form data
                profile_data = request.POST.dict()
                # get current user profile
                user_profile = Profile.objects.get(my_user=request.user)
                # check username entry against current
                if user_profile.username == profile_data['username']:
                    messages.success(request, "This is the current user.")
                else:
                    try:
                        # try to save the new username
                        user_profile.username = profile_data['username']
                        user_profile.save(update_fields=['username'])
                        messages.success(request, "Success: Username was updated.")
                    except:
                        # unique constraint error on username
                        # ERROR PROCESSING NEEDED
                        # Need to send error to form for user to correct and resubmit???
            
        # return get request to process any updated data
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a form class that takes care of the form data and it could also repopulate the data.

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label="Username",
        help_text="(create a unique display name that will appear to other users on the site)",
    )
```

views.py

```
class ProfileView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # get request...


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
                user_profile = Profile.objects.get(my_user=request.user)

                if user_profile.username == username:
                    messages.success(request, "This is the current user.")
                else:
                    try:
                        user_profile.username = username
                        user_profile.save(update_fields=["username"])
                        messages.success(request, "Success: Username was updated.")
                    except IntegrityError:
                        messages.error(request, "Error message which should be displayed")
                        return render(
                            request, "your_form.html", {"form": form}
                        )

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
```

Comment: I am not able to get this code past form.is_valid().  If I print form it is printing the actual html of username field <input type="text" name="username" value="testingusername" required id="id_username">.  Am I missing something in the above example?  I copied it directly.

Comment: Have you imported ProfileForm (or placed in the same file)?

Comment: Yes, however I think the problem is that I am not using {{ form }} in the template?  I am specifically rending these forms manually because I have multiple forms on the same page and in the same view.  Does your above approach work with that?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You can pass as many form instances to the template as you want. Just add them to the context where you render the template like `{"form1": form1, "form2": form2, ...}`. Then render them accordingly `{{ form1 }}` within the template.
If you use crispy-forms, you can output bootstrap forms with ease. Furthermore, the crispy [form helper](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#crispy-tag-forms) give you a way to control form attributes and its layout, doing this in a programmatic way using Python.

Comment: well dang.  worked like a charm!  Thanks.